# Easiest feature mapper in python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to make an easiest possible feature mapper using python3. Two purposes: to receive the best performance and to understand how to program python :)

Here is my code, it doesn't work:

```
import pandas as pd
source = pd.DataFrame({'Country' : ['USA', 'USA', 'Russia','USA'], 
                  'City' : ['New-York1', 'New-York', 'Sankt-Petersburg', 'New-York']})

#trim column value selecting first two symbols
def s_trim(x):
    return x[:2]

#make new column from two selecting first two symbols from each
def s_trim_concat(x,y):
    return '%s-%s' % (x[:2],y[:2])

features = [
    ('trim',['Country'],s_trim),
    ('trim1',['Country','City'],s_trim_concat),
    ('trim2',['City','Country'],s_trim_concat)
    ]

for feature_name, columns, func in features:
    source[feature_name] = source[columns].apply(func, axis=1)

print(source)
```

UPDATE: Now the code works, but I've had to complicate functions, so I'm still looking for good solutions that allows to use simple functions without type conversions inside:

```
import pandas as pd
source = pd.DataFrame({'Country' : ['USA', 'USA', 'Russia','USA'], 
                  'City' : ['New-York1', 'New-York', 'Sankt-Petersburg', 'New-York']})

#trim column value selecting first two symbols
def s_trim(x):
    return x.str[:2]

#make new column from two selecting first two symbols from each
def s_trim_concat(row):
    x = row[0]
    y = row[1]
    return '%s-%s' % (x[:2],y[:2])

features = [
    ('trim',['Country'],s_trim),
    ('trim1',['Country','City'],s_trim_concat),
    ('trim2',['City','Country'],s_trim_concat)
    ]

for feature_name, columns, func in features:
    if len(columns) == 1:
        source[feature_name] = source[columns].apply(func)
    else:
        source[feature_name] = source[columns].apply(func, axis=1)
print(source)
```

Comment: What's this supposed to do?

Comment: Before solving classification or regression tasks I want to add new transformed columns i.e. to clean up source data or to normalize them.

Comment: In my sample code I expect s_trim to cat column to two symbols and s_trim_concat - to make one column from two. I.e. for 'USA','New-York' to get 'US-Ne'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably I've found a solution:

```
import pandas as pd
source = pd.DataFrame({'Country' : ['USA', 'USA', 'Russia','USA'], 
                  'City' : ['New-York1', 'New-York', 'Sankt-Petersburg', 'New-York']})

#trim column value selecting first two symbols
def s_trim(x):
    return x.str[:2]

#make new column from two selecting first two symbols from each
def s_trim_concat(x,y):
    return '%s-%s' % (x[:2],y[:2])

features = [
    ('trim',['Country'],s_trim),
    ('trim1',['Country','City'],s_trim_concat),
    ('trim2',['City','Country'],s_trim_concat)
    ]

for feature_name, columns, func in features:
    source[feature_name] = source[columns].apply(
        func if len(columns) == 1 
        else lambda x: func(x[0],x[1]), axis=1)
print(source)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are passing a list into s_trim_concat rather than two separate arguments.

Can you provide a sample of what the final output should look like for this example. For a start I need to clarify what key should the value returned from s_trim_concat be associated with?

**UPDATE**

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
source = pd.DataFrame({'Country' : ['USA', 'USA', 'Russia','USA'], 
                  'City' : ['New-York1', 'New-York', 'Sankt-Petersburg', 'New-York']})

#trim column value selecting first two symbols
def s_trim(x):
    return x[:2]

#make new column from two selecting first two symbols from each
def s_trim_concat(x,y):
    return '%s-%s' % (x[:2],y[:2])

features = [
    ('trim',['Country'],s_trim),
    ('trim1',['Country','City'],s_trim_concat),
    ('trim2',['City','Country'],s_trim_concat)
    ]

for feature_name, columns, func in features:
    source[feature_name] = apply(func, columns)

print(source)
```

Comment: I'm going to get 'trim' as 'US','US','Ru','US' and 'trim1' as 'US-Ne', 'US-Ne', 'Ru-Sa', 'US-Ne'. In my post I pointer wrong column names, corrected.

Comment: apply() function doesn't work in your solution - python cannot find it